# none.xml:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in android studio

Tags: android, xml

In Android studio after running the following code, it says"none.xml:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document"

what is the problem? its the code that i copied from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

the code is here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```